# How do I "do something" after delete with Silverstripe

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I am Using SilverStripe and have a DataObject lets call it books and I want to be able to process something when the book is deleted from the database.

There is no onAfterDelete method but it does call the onAfterWrite method but I need to be able to tell the difference between an addition and deletion.

**Example:**
When I add a book to the system using the CMS I want to be able to add it to the library and set some other data up.
When I delete the book from the system within the CMS I want to be able to remove it from the library and then remove the other data I setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the API for SS 3 there are hooks on DataObject for `onBeforeDelete` and `onAfterDelete` http://api.silverstripe.org/3.0/source-class-DataObject.html#962-974

Remember to call `parent::onBefore....` and you can do whatever you want there....

Comment: Looks like I was missing the parent::onAfterDelete so it didn't run :S